# Python Import function from another file not working

Tags: python, python-import, importerror

I'm facing a problem with importing functions from another file that is not working.

Here is the simplify tree of my folders, located on `/var/www/html/opencaptureforinvoices/` :

```
├── custom
│   └── test
│       └── src
│           └── backend
│               └── process_queue.py
└── src
    └── backend
        └── main.py
```

I run the `process_queue.py` script with the following command, using Kuyruk (lib to enqueue process)

```
cd /var/www/html/opencaptureforinvoices/custom/test || exit
/usr/local/bin/kuyruk --app src.backend.process_queue_verifier.kuyruk worker --queue
```

The problem is that I need function from `main.py`. I use import like this :

```
from src.backend.main import create_classes_from_custom_id, check_file, timer, str2bool
```

Before posting I tried to rewrite the path to the root of `custom` & `src` using `sys.path.append` or `sys.path.insert` or `os.path.chdir` but none of them working, the application said to me :

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src.backend.main'
```

Here is the command I tried to move to root folder :

```
os.chdir('/var/www/html/opencaptureforinvoices/')
sys.path.append('/var/www/html/opencaptureforinvoices/')
sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/html/opencaptureforinvoices/')
```

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `.src.backend.main`?

Answer (score 0):

First solution:

Make sure the folder also contains an __ init __.py, this allows it to be included as a package.

Second:

When importing a file, Python only searches the directory that the entry-point script is running from and sys.path which includes locations such as the package installation directory.

But you can add to the Python path at runtime:

some_file.py

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/application/app/folder')

import file
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you set up your subdirectories as packages using the `__init__.py` file?

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages

> The `__init__.py` files are required to make Python treat directories
> containing the file as packages. This prevents directories with a
> common name, such as string, unintentionally hiding valid modules that
> occur later on the module search path. In the simplest case,
> `__init__.py` can just be an empty file, but it can also execute initialization code for the package or set the `__all__` variable,
> described later.
>
> Users of the package can import individual modules from the package,
> for example:
>
> `import sound.effects.echo`